# ASP .NET MVC Let admin change contents of view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have built a website where the customer wants the opportunity to change contents of the views.

The way I see will be the most easy is to let him insert HTML into the database, then it will be printed out. Only  the administrators will be able to insert anything into the database. 
I have already implemented so the views will print out text with html tags.

So, the question is:

What can I use to insert text and html tags into the database? I tried with copy-paste, but it will stop paste when there is a whitespace between html tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just CMS functionality, then you are on the way to make it. It's true that admins might store some part of content, and post in unencoded, just to make browser be able to understand markup code.

But if your intention is to customize views itself, with remaining rest of content to stay the same, it is some kind on theming. E.g. using different Views in different Themes.
 There are plenty of ways how to implement theming: XSLT, Templating etc.

Comment: In my case I want be able to change contents of my pages via adminpage, instead of edit html files then upload it. Is it a safe enough and will it be fast enough if all views need to print 400-500words from database?

Comment: It is how it's made in other CMS systems. You just have to be careful and keep in mind possibility of XSS, XSRF atacks.